# jquery plugin, multi-type (value, control id, function) options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a plugin I am writing that accepts options.  It looks something like this.

```
$('#myObject').myPlugin({
    option1: someValue
});
```

Where `somevalue` can either be a value, a control id, or a function.

I have a default settings defined like this

```
var settings = {
    option1: null
};
```

Then, inside my plugin I use this to merge what the user passes in with my empty settings object

```
if (options) {
    $.extend(settings, options);
}
```

This works fine when the option is a control ID or value.

My first issue is when I use a function like this

```
$('#myObject').myPlugin({
    option1: function(){ return doStuff(); }
});
```

`$.extend()` seems to ignore the function in this case.  The default value from `settings` is always passed into my parser.  I'm also having a problem when I pass in a value instead of a control id.  I parse the settings to get the value like this

```
function parseValue(value, defaultValue) {
    if ($.isFunction(value))
        return value();

    if (!value)
        return defaultValue ? defaultValue : '';

    if ($('#' + value))
        return $('#' + value).val();

    return value;
};
```

if I pass in a date or a decimal, `$('#' + value)` evaluates to true.

Any ideas on how I make this work?

EDIT:

This may be wrong, but this is how I defined my plugin.  It's actually a collection of plugins

```
(function ($) {

    //shared methods here
    function parseValue(value, defaultValue) { /*...*/ }

    $.fn.myplugin = function (options) {
        var settings = { };

        $(this).live("submit", function (event) {
            //NEVER EVER EVER allow the form to submit to the server
            event.preventDefault();

            //logic for "posting" cross domain
        });
    };

    $.fn.myplugin2 = function (options) {
        var settings = { };

        $(this).live("submit", function (event) {
            //NEVER EVER EVER allow the form to submit to the server
            event.preventDefault();

            //logic for "posting" cross domain
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

The plugins hijack a form and make it submit cross domain through a jsonp get request.  Each plugin submits different data to a different url, but the overall logic is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

The selector test I was doing was always returning false because jquery doesn't return undefined if nothing was found.  So, I changed my parser to look like this:

```
function parseValue(value, defaultValue) {
    if ($.isFunction(value))
        return value();

    if (!value)
        return defaultValue;

    if ($.type(value) === 'string' && $(value).length)
        return $(value).val();

    return value;
};
```

and my code now looks something like this

```
$.fn.myPlugin= function (options) {

    var settings = {
        setting1: undefined
    }

    $(this).live('click', function{
        var setting = parseValue(settings.setting1, '');
    });
}
```

and now all three types (value, selector, or function) can be passed in as my query options.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do an `$.extend()` for your plugin options.  The plugin infrastructure should automatically merge the options passed in by the caller with the default options.  For example, given this plugin:

```
$.widget(
    'myPlugin',
    {
        options: {
            option1: undefined
        },

        _create: function() {
        }
    }
);
```

And this call:

```
foo.myPlugin({option1: function() { } });
```

`options.option1` should be properly populated with the function.

Comment: I have my plugin built in entirely different way.  Maybe they way I built it is wrong.

Comment: Ah, somehow I missed that you weren't using the jQuery widget framework.  You ought to consider using that; it makes a lot of common tasks much easier.

Comment: I tried moving my code into a widget and I have the same error.  The function is not set into the options property by the same name.  I initialize is as undefined and it is passed into my parse method as undefined.