# building jQuery plugIn

Tags: asp.net, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I'm building an easy plugIn for validations, after setting up some options to be editable,
and after cycling all the fields i wrote:

```
$(this).submit(function () {
```

where "this" is the main element (the form).

Now I was wondering to use this plug-in in asp.net as well, so without using an html form, where there are just some inputs into a div and on click on a specific button it start...

So I know that here I have to change the submit... and trying to bind it on click of the button... I don't know how to solve this...

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need help to bind a click event? For that you write

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(e)
{
   // do some logic

   e.preventDefault(); // make sure that ie. a href is not followed
});
```

Comment: I need to do that but the function must start the validation on the parent div! How to do that?

Comment: i don't know your exact dom structure, but if you just need the parent you can use the parent() function http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at what I was doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760806/jquery-plugin-multi-type-value-control-id-function-options).  My plugin hijacks a form post to submit data cross domain to my server instead of the hosting server.  The overall method could be used for your validation.

here's a quick and dirty example of my code.

```
$.fn.myplugin= function (options) {

    var settings = {
        setting1: undefined,
        setting2: undefined,
        setting3: undefined,

        beforeSubmit: function () { return true; },
        afterSubmit: function () { },
        approve: function () { },
        decline: function () { },
        error: function () { },
        exception: function (xhr, status, error) { }
    };

    // If options exist, lets merge them
    // with our default settings
    if (options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    //ensure this is attached only to a FORM element
    if (!$(this).is("form"))
        throw ('Specified object is not a valid form.  This plugin can only be attached to a form element.');

    $(this).live("submit", function (event) {
        var result = true;

        //NEVER EVER EVER allow the form to submit to the server
        event.preventDefault();

        if (settings.beforeSubmit)
            result = settings.beforeSubmit();

        if (result != null && !result)
            return false;

        //do stuff

    }); //end live submit

};
```

Then, usage looks like this

```
$('#form-id').myplugin({
    setting1: 'value',
    setting2: 'value',
    setting3: 'value'
});
```

Comment: I don't understand where I can remove the form and allow a simple div to be cycled and validated...